# Assigning variables over multiple DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas

I have 5 separate DataFrames, person1 - person5 where `id` is the column name. 
I want to assign the `id` column of each DataFrame to a variable. I have to copy and paste text often because I don't know how to loop over the DataFrames. I tried using `eval` and `exec` along with other methods but with no success.

```
id1 = person1.id
id2 = person2.id
id3 = person3.id
id4 = person4.id
id5 = person5.id
```

Comment: Consider to have a list of persons, list_persons = [person1, person2, person3 ...]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to do it like this:

```
for x in range(1,6): 
  exec(f'id{x} = person{x}.id')
```

Comment: Thanks man this works. What does the "f" do? I tried it without and it didn't work.

Comment: it let's you use the x variable in the {}. it;s a python 3 feature to let you use variables in strings

Answer (score 0):

you can put your `dataframes` into a list and then loop through the list:

```
ldf = [person1,person2,person3,person4,person5]
lid = {}
for i in range(1, len(ldf)+1):
    lid[f'id{i}'] = ldf[i].id
```

Now you have all your `id` in a `lid`